# Looking to switch to VS 2013/MVC for web development but need to support IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8, asp.net-mvc-5

Our current development is in VS 2008 using WebForms and JQuery. **We must support IE8**.

For new projects I would like to start using VS 2013/MVC but I am not sure if support of IE8 will be an issue. I have used VS 2013 for short time on co-worker's PC and I noticed it includes JQuery, Bootstrap, modernizr-2.6.2.js and respond.js frameworks (of those I am only a bit familiar with JQuery) in project generated from MVC template. Note that I am fairly new to web development and JavaScript in particular.

JQuery used in this project is version 1.10.2 and 1.* JQuery branch supports IE8.

Bootstrap is v. 3.0.0 and IE8 support has some limitations as I found here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support Are these a big deal/show stoppers? Are there workarounds?

Information I found on modernizr is not completely clear. On one hand this page http://modernizr.com/docs/ says: **"We support IE6+, Firefox 3.5+, Opera 9.6+, Safari 2+, Chrome."**. On the other hand the same page says: "**If you don't support IE8 and don't need to worry about FOUC, feel free to include modernizr.js whereever."**

As far as respond.js it seems there are some issues for which people usually find workarounds.

Are there any issues inherent to latest version of MVC itself (other than JavaScript component compatibility) that make it incompatible with IE8?

Comment: Browser compatibility depends on features used in the HTML, CSS and JavaScript on page. This has nothing at all to do with server technologies or versions thereof. You can use ASP.NET vNext to generate code compatible with Netscape Navigator (if you could find something still around to run it on). One has nothing to do with the other.

Comment: I was not aware all these JavaScript components are optional in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 5 itself should not have any compatibility issues with IE8. The Javascript libraries *might* have issues, but that depends on the developer.

By using VS2013/MVC and their project template, you're not required to use Bootstrap, Modernizr or whatever they include. If you don't need it, you can just remove the references. You can also manually add-in an older version of the libraries, if they do support IE8.